# Custom UIView prevents scrolling of MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, mkmapview

I've got MKMapView(map) which got a subview UIView(logo) added with addSubview method. How can i make UIView transparent for actions that intended to MKMapView? I want to scroll map even if i start action from logo territory.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that property userInteractionEnabled should be NO.